# How to create a priority service thread pool in jboss

Tags: jboss

I have deployed 2 war files in jboss 6.4 (SupposeA.war and B.war) ,I want A.war to be deployed first then B deployment should start.

Is there any way to do it.

This is required as my B.war is dependent on A.war.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jboss-all.xml deployment file (located under B.war/WEB-INF/jboss-all.xml) and it should be something like:

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
     <dependency name="a.war" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

Now B will start after A has been deployed. The same file works for any top level deployment, as an ear.

Comment: Thanks @Gerado Arroyo, it worked fine, I have one more query, suppose I have A.war,B.war and C.war and I want to deploy first A.war then B.war and then C.war, so can I put the same jboss-all.xml in C.war and add the dependency of A.war and B.war in one file?

Scenario is C. war is dependent on A.war and B.war but A.war and B.war are independent

Comment: Yes, that is correct @AkashMishra.  You can put the deployment file in C.war and the dependency will be A and B.

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo Arroyo, one more query I have, if I want to check a condition that if A.war is present then check for dependency or ignore, can we do that?. This is required as there are scenarios where A.war and B.war can be deployed at different jboss port. in this scenario, my B.war will still check for A.war dependency and it will never start.